# Quando e porque se deve usar um método estático?

Tags: php, java, c#, orientação-a-objetos

Sempre tive essa dúvida em questão da POO, vejo muitos códigos com *static methods* e agora iniciando em C# não é diferente. Sendo direto, quando se deve usar esse tipo de método, o porque de usar ele e a sua principal função! Obrigado!

Comment: Quando quiser usar o método sem precisar instanciar um objeto.

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado Jbueno! :D

Comment: Não vou criar uma resposta e dar detalhes pq tô pelo celular. Fora isso, acho que já tem isso no site, mas não consegui achar nada. De qualquer forma, se tiver alguma resposta vai ser linkada aqui, caso contrário alguém vai escrever uma resposta.

Comment: Eu consegui entender pela sua resposta, estava com o Visual Studio aberto e escrevi algumas linhas de código testando a sua resposta e consegui entender. Agradeço a ajuda.